# Verifying that a function is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $G,H$ be groups. let $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut} (G) $ and $\psi \in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$

Now let's construct the mapping:

$F(\phi, \psi): G \times H \rightarrow G \times H$ defined by $(g,h) \mapsto (\phi(g), \psi(h))$

I'm trying to verify that $F$ is well defined:

Here's my reasonning:

suppose $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2, y_2)$, then, $F( \phi, \psi)(x_1,y_1)= (\phi(x_1), \psi(y_1)) = (\phi(x_2), \psi(y_2))$ (because $\phi$ and $\psi$ are well defined) $= F( \phi, \psi)(x_2,y_2)$

Therefore, $F$ is well defined.

Is that the right way to approach the problem?

Comment: All you've done is written out the definition of $F$.  What does "well-defined" mean here?  Are you meant to show that $F$ is an automorphism of $G\times H$?

Comment: Yes, you've shown that the map is well-defined.  If the inputs are equal, even if they're expressed in different ways, you get the same answer.  However, I would suggest not putting the parenthetical in the middle of the line of equations.